# difference between sourceCpp and Rcpp.package.skeleton

Tags: windows, r, rcpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector condSumRcpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, LogicalVector z) {

  int n = x.length();
  int sumLength = sum(z);

  NumericVector res(sumLength);
  int j=0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!z[i]) continue;
    res[j] = x[i] + y[i];
    j+=1;
  }

  return wrap(res);
 }
```

This works fine when I use sourceCpp. However when I use

```
Rcpp.package.skeleton("testRcpp",
  example_code = FALSE,
  cpp_files="utils.cpp",
  module=FALSE
)
```

and build the package with `R CMD INSTALL --build testRcpp` I get

```
Error in .Call("testRcpp_condSumRcpp", PACKAGE = "testRcpp", x, y, z) : 
  "testRcpp_condSumRcpp" not available for .Call() for package "testRcpp"
```

If I do the same process with

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector colMaxRcpp(NumericMatrix X) {

    int ncol = X.ncol();
    NumericVector res(ncol);

    for (int col = 0; col < ncol; col++){
        res[col]=Rcpp::max(X(_, col)); 
    }

    return wrap(res);
}
```

then it works!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot randomly mix Attributes and `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.

I usually create an empty package first (via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` or the corresponding feature in RStudio) and then add my function.  Call `compileAttributes()` and you should be good.